# How to add Html markup written in C# dynamically in to .aspx using Ajax UpdatePanel's content Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, .net-4.0

I have the below code (.Aspx.cs),

```
StringBuilder strMarkup = new StringBuilder();
strMarkup.AppendFormat("<div id=" + "MyDiv" + "><table id= " + "sDetails" +      ">" +
"<tr><td><input id= " + "lblStudentName" + " type=" + "text" + " value = " + "StudentName" + "/> </td>" +
"<td> <input id= " + "dispStudentName" + " type=" + "text" + " value = {0}/> </td>" +
"</tr>" +
"<tr><td><input id= " + "lblCourseName" + " type=" + "text" + " value = " +  "StudentName" + "/> </td>" +
"<td> <input id= " + "dispCourseName" + " type=" + "text" + " value = {1}/> </td>" +
"</tr></table></div>", _studentName, _courseName);
```

Which I want to load the above thing into an Ajax UpdatePanel Where my .aspx page is as below:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateDetails" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="StudentDetialsPanel" runat= "server">
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnSubmit" EventName="" />
    </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

Use [InnerHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml.aspx) property of panel to assign the html you have to panel in `UpdatePanel`

```
StudentDetialsPanel.InnerHtml = strMarkup.ToString();
```

Comment: I can't see a InnerHtml property in an asp:Panel!